# How to build libxerces-c for Windows 32-bit from CMake generated Visual Studio project files?

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, xerces-c

I'm trying to build libxerces-c for Windows. Instruction on their xerces site looks like this:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -G "Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=D:\libs    \path\to\xerces-c\source
cmake --build . --config Debug
ctest -V -C Debug -j 4
cmake --build . --config Debug --target install
```

I'm using VS2017 so using this instead: "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64"

Looking at the generated VS project file only x64 platform is generated. I tried changing "Win64" to "Win32" and "x86", but get and error that only "Win64" and "ARM" are available:

```
cmake .. -G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win32"
CMake Error: Could not create named generator Visual Studio 15 2017 Win32

Generators
  Visual Studio 16 2019        = Generates Visual Studio 2019 project files.
                                 Use -A option to specify architecture.
* Visual Studio 15 2017 [arch] = Generates Visual Studio 2017 project files.
                                 Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "ARM".
  Visual Studio 14 2015 [arch] = Generates Visual Studio 2015 project files.
                                 Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "ARM".
  Visual Studio 12 2013 [arch] = Generates Visual Studio 2013 project files.
```

Can I control this from CMake somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Reading more carefully I see Win64/ARM are OPTIONAL. Omitting arch gives me the x86 platform:

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 14 2015" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=D:\libs
```